# Single Folder - Multiple Git Platforms

Tags: git, github

Remotely deploy same folder on Github and Heroku Git.

**Example:**

Here both are added to their remote location.

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/thawing-inlet-61413.git

git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

**Question is**

My folder will be exactly the same.

How to push on both Github and Heroku Git.

Number of commands doesn't matter to me.

If something like this is possible,

```
git push heroku master    //Just an example
git push origin master    //Example
```

That would work for me. But is it possible and how?

Comment: Which CLI? Windows or UNIX?

Comment: I'm using MacOS

Comment: Are you asking how to push to both remotes in a single command? Or how to push to either one of them based on your current need?

Comment: @Chris, please check my edit.

Comment: Why don't you try running those commands with [the `--dry-run` argument](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---dry-run) and see if they do what you want?

Comment: Sure, thank you @Chris will get back to you with the results :)